# CDF of a mixture of Normal Distribution

Tags: probability, normal-distribution

I have a mixture of Normal distributions, with the parameters and the weight of each law in the mixture known. Is it true to said that the CDF of the mixture is the sum of the CDF of each law multiply by their weights ?

For example, if I have $N(\mu_1, \sigma_1)$ with a weight $w_1$ and $M(\mu_2, \sigma_2)$ with a weight $w_2$,  is it true to say that $CDF(w_1N(\mu_1, \sigma_1) + w_2M(\mu_2, \sigma_2)) = w_1CDF(N(\mu_1, \sigma_1)) + w_2CDF(M(\mu_2, \sigma_2))$ ?

Thank you very much.

Comment: No. You are confusing the mixture distribution and the summation of distributions. $w_1N+w_2M$ (no constraint is required on $w$) is a random variable and is dependent on the covariance between $N,M$. On the other hand, the mixture distribution describes a CDF $F_X$ such that $$F_X(x)=w_1F_N(x)+w_2F_M(x)$$ which determines a random variable $X$, but $X$ may not be the weighted sum. You might want to google "Summation of normal distributions" for more information.

Comment: Hello and thanks for your answer. I think what I want is related to mixture distribution. I have already done a post : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2211206/sum-of-gaussian-curves/2211221#2211221 for sum of Gaussian curves. What I need from now is to be able to get the probability $P(a < X < b)$, so I need to work on the CDF of the sum. Using your formula of CDF $F_X$ is OK then ? As english is not my mother tongue, I am using the term "sum" for "mixture" here. I am going to edit the post.

Comment: since you mean the mixture model, then the CDF is rather simple as shown in my comment. You can calculate any probability using that definition. However, The mixture May no longer be Gaussian.

Comment: Ok, that's great. But there is something I don't get and maybe you can give some clues. You said that no constraints are required on $w$, but how could it work ? If $\sum_i^nw_n > 1$, you are goingto have $F_X(x) > 1$, which is not really possible, don't you think ?

Comment: well, no constraint is required for the *sum* of random variables. But what you're talking about is the mixture of random variables.

Comment: You need to distinguish between a (weighted) sum and a mixture. A (weighted) sum is just a linear transformation like $\displaystyle Y = \sum_{i=1}^n w_iX_i$. The CDF of the weighted sum, in general is not equal to the weighted sum of individual CDF. On the other hand, for a mixture distribution, you are like throwing a $n$-sided dice, and then generate the random variable according to that face. Assuming the independence of those random variables, by law of total probability, the CDF of the mixture will satisfy the equation you posted.

Comment: Hello, thanks for the information. Do you know if there is a "simple" way to check the independency of those variables ? The CDF looks pretty OK and I am pretty sure the random variables are independent, but I would like to prove it more formally.